# How to transfer POST Variables via Twig path() function

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm struggeling to find an answer on following question.

How can i transfer Variables with the POST-Method by using Twig's path() function in a Symfony2 project.
Or: 
How can I define the Method in the path() function.

```
    Controller:
    /**
     * @Route('_route', name='_route')
     * @Method ????
     */
    public function pageAction(){ ... }

    Twig:

    {{ path('_route', {'slug': slug, 'POST-VARIABLE' : value}) }}
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Why don't you just use `@Method('GET')` ?

Comment: You **definitely** should use GET method isntead of POST one or just rethink your approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to create a `POST` request in twig.

You can only create a *url* (that can contain GET query-parameters) using the `path` function.

You could create a `<form>` with `method="POST"` that a user can click though.